# ActiveRecord Autosave in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sidekiq

I am not sure how Ruby uses ActiveRecord to save data directly in the model code. How can I save data into the DB in the model itself?
Basically my code run into a race condition for the following reason (Ruby/rails + ActiveRecord + Sidekiq):
- My model does something like the following:

```
def is_present?(data)
    memory['properties'].include?(data)

def update_mem(data, size)
    if size != 0 && memory['properties'].length == amount
         memory['properties'].shift
    memory['properties'].push(data)
```

It checks if a specific value is present (is_present), if it is not present in the memory['properties'] yet, it will add it.

- Clearly if there is only one thread accessing "memory", it works just fine but since Sidekiq is pretty fast there might be multiple threads running and will end up in a race condition (one thread write something, the other thread read what was in memory before).

"memory" is actually a column in a table (MySQL) and as soon as I write something in it with "memory['properties'].push(123)" I would like to save them immediately.

My question is, how can I prevent this weird race condition?
What I would like to do is to save the data directly in the DB using the model. The problem is that it seems is not working.

So, to access the data in the model, I use the following code:
memory['property'].push(123)
or
self.memory['property'].push(123)

They both reference the memory column in the DB table.

But then I want to do something like self.save! but it is not working at all.

I tried to add the following code in the model iteself:

```
self.memory_will_change!
self.memory['properties'].push(property)
self.save!
```

Unfortunately, it is not working and I cannot save the data into the DB.

This model is actually called via perform() using Sidekiq as per below:

```
model = Receivers.find(id)
model.receive(data)
model.time = Time.now
model.save!
```

So the time is updated correctly but the memory (which is updated in the model when i call "receive") it does not get updated. Anyone knows how to overcome this problem? I need to save the data into the DB directly in the model.

Thanks and I look forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use a lock so that only one process can access the table at a time. Once you are done processing, you would release the lock.

Check out the following link:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html

Comment: I already tried and this does not work as it will lock the row for too long and it will timeout other requests. I might have found the solution with some autosave + sync.